# What does $\Bbb N^n$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

What does $\Bbb N^n$ exactly mean?

E.g. (...) nonnegative integer solutions
$(y_1, . . . , y_n) \in \Bbb N^n$
.

Comment: this refers to the collection of  ordered $n-$ tuples of natural numbers.

Comment: If, for example, $\mathbb N$ means $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$, then $\mathbb N^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers.  Also written $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times \dots \times \mathbb N$, where there are $n$ factors.

Comment: I wouldn't say "solutions," but yes, it is all $n$-tuples of natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah the "solution" was part of the rest of the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have two sets $A$ and $B$, you can have their *cartesian product*: the set of "ordered pairs" or "2-tuples" $(a,b)$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. You can also obtain the cartesian product of any number of sets you want to: $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$ would contain the n-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ where $a_i\in A_i$.

A particular case of this is having $A_1 = \cdots = A_n = A$, in which case $A\times \cdots \times A$ can be denoted as $A^n$.

Thus the set $\mathbb{N}^n$ contains n-tuples of natural numbers. For instance, $(1,2)\in\mathbb{N}^2$.

It is important to remark that, for example, $(1,2) \neq (2,1)$ as *a tuple is nothing more than a collection of ordered elements*.